# Le verbe « to bail (out) » : lequel de renflouer, aider, sauver, tirer/sortir d'affaire est-il le plus adéquat dans ce contexte ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/economie/automobile/201901/12/01-5210813-unifor-mise-sur-la-pub-pour-denoncer-general-motors.php) il y a une image dans laquelle un employé de l'usine de General Motors à Oshawa (Ontario, Canada) porte un vêtement sur lequel est écrit :

> Canada didn't *bail out* GM to move our jobs to Mexico.

[image]

<sup><sup>Détail d'une photo de Rebecca Cook (Reuters) ds. La Presse.</sup></sup>

Il s'agit du sens « to help (a business, an organization, etc.) by giving or lending money » ([Merriam Learners](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/bail)) et au [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17040449) on propose les verbes *renflouer, aider, sauver, [tirer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirer) d'affaire* alors que sur [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/bail/564262#564263) on suggère [*tirer/sortir d'affaire*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/affaire/1388/locution?q=tirer%20d%27affaire#167687).

- Lequel aurait-on choisi pour faire partie d'une phrase s'apparentant à un slogan (sur un vêtement) ou autrement quel(le) verbe/expression emploierait-on, et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 1):

« Renflouer » selon l'acception considérée et le TLFi, est [courant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/renflouer) en français français ; cela est confirmé par le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/renflouer/68167). « to bail out sb » est aussi considéré comme courant en anglais anglais (Oxford dictionary). The Cambridge dictionary also lists that word as standard, [not at all informal, nor slang](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/bail-sb-sth-out).

Seul le terme « renflouer » semble un terme spécifique au domaine de la finance en français français.

> (TLFi)  b) Au fig. **Fait de rétablir une situation financière compromise.** Le capitalisme défaillant a appelé la collectivité au secours; celle-ci a procédé à des renflouements en prenant des participations en capital (Univers écon. et soc., 1960, p. 22-12).

Je n'ai jamais remarqué les expressions verbales « aider », «sauver » et « tirer d'affaire » dans ce contexte ; de plus, ou bien elles ne sont pas portées dans le TLFi (tirer d'affaire) ou bien ne figure dans ce dictionaire aucune définition spécialisée à la finance (aider, sauver).

Comment: @subsexdexter 1/ j'ai aussi remarqué cela, mais dans tous les cas le terme est général, pas un terme spécifique à la finance ; comme, de plus, je suis habitué à ne trouver pratiquement que le terme « renflouer » dans un contexte financier je conçois « renflouer » comme le terme prioritaire ; cependant il n'est pas interdit d'introduire une nuance inhabituelle ou un quasi synonyme, pour changer, et de se rabattre sur un terme général. D'ailleurs, aucun de ces termes généraux ne sont informels. 2/ Les dictionnaires de Cambridge pourraient n'être que des dictionnaires comme (champ suivant)

Comment: @subsexdexter mais je dispose de deux dictionnaire d'Oxford qui ne mentionnent pas non plus quoi que ce soit en ce qui concerne le registre et je dois dire que ces derniers corroborent très souvent mes hypothèses en matière de sens des mots. J'aurais dû écrire dans ma réponse « seul terme spécifique du domaine de la finance », ce que je vais faire. (Il semble qu'il existe un schisme symbolisé par l'océan Atlantique  en ce qui concerne ce concept.) 3/ Le problème, il me semble, est que hors de contexte ni « sauver » ni « tirer d'affaire » ne soient suffisamment spécifiques (champ suivant)

Comment: @subsexdexter  alors que « renflouer » serait possiblement plus apte ; ce qui semble manquer c'est un terme choc, propre à la langue des T-shirts!

Answer (score 1):

Une situation qui présente plusieurs points communs avec celle de la question pourrait inspirer ce slogan :

> *La France n'a pas injecté 100 millions d'Euros à Blanquefort pour que Ford ferme et vire tous le monde.*